# Silex: Spika Server throws NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /api"

Tags: php, api, symfony

I get this error on page.

[image]

I'm sure other people are having the same issue. https://github.com/cloverstudio/Spika-Server/issues/24.

All the code is [here](https://github.com/cloverstudio/Spika-Server) And here's my `api.php`

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../etc/app.php';

$app->run();
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve it?

Comment: Could you please include **how** you have set up your application ( steps taken so far, which vagrant/application version ) ? Otherwise nobody can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I figured it out. The error is normal.

Answer (score 1):

The error is normal. You just continue with development.

Comment: I also face the same issue while installig spika, How to complete the installation and start development ?